# Can We use @dataprovider and @parameters annotations on the same method?

Tags: java, selenium, annotations

This is the sample program in this way I have tried. But this is not working. And throwing dataProvider mismatch error.

```
public class dataprovide {
  @Test (dataProvider="providerData")
  @Parameters("num")
  public void f(int number, int expected,int num) {
      Assert.assertEquals(number +num, expected);   //num =10 in testng.xml

       //throw new SkipException("Message");
  }
  @DataProvider/*(name = "provideNumber")*/
    public Object[][] providerData()
    {
      return new Object[][]{
          {10,20}, {100,110}
      };
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using testNG? can you show your code what have you tried ?

Comment: public class dataprovide {
  @Test (dataProvider="providerData")
  @Parameters("num")
  public void f(int number, int expected,int num) {
   Assert.assertEquals(number +num, expected); //num =10 in testng.xml
  
    //throw new SkipException("Message");
  }
  @DataProvider/*(name = "provideNumber")*/
   public Object[][] providerData()
   {
   return new Object[][]{
    {10,20}, {100,110}
   };
   }
}

Comment: i would suggest you to edit question and put it in there as code for better readability, so you have a better chance of getting an answer from someone

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `context.getCurrentXmlTest()` or save your param in `@beforclass`. both are illustrated below

```
@BeforeClass
  @Parameters({"testParam"})
  public void init(String suiteParam) {
    this.suiteParam = suiteParam;
  }


@DataProvider(name = "testDataProvider")
  public Object[][] createData1(ITestContext context) {
      String testParam = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("testParam");

       int theNums[][] = new int[][] {{10,20},{100,110}};


   return new Object[][] {

       { testParam, theNums }

  };

  }



  @Test(dataProvider = "testDataProvider")

  public  void testingParam( String DPparam1, int[][] DPparam2) {

      System.out.println("xml param through data provider: " + DPparam1);
      System.out.println("configured param from data provider: " + DPparam2[0][0]);
      System.out.println("xml param from @beforeclass: " + suiteParam);
      }
```

and in xml its like this

```
<parameter name="testParam" value="test123"/>
```

the above prints

```
xml param through data provider: test123
configured param from data provider: 10
xml param from @beforeclass: test123
```